# samsung pc studio not install on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tethering, gprs

i want to install samsung pc studio for make a internet connection via GPRS on ubuntu 9.10 but without this software it is not possible so give me suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Samsung PC Studio seems to be Win-Only software...your best bet would be WINE, but the AppDB [rates the software as garbage](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5233). Maybe you can use the phone as a direct GPRS-Modem (knowing what phone you have would help here).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply. By now, you may have shifted to 10.10! However, I think you can plug on your phone, and the network manager would recognise it instantly. Just click on the NM, go through the create network connection option to fill up the wizard, and you are connected!